# Issue with 'IndexError: string index out of range'

Tags: python, python-3.x, encryption, index-error

new Python user here.

I'm writing a piece of encryption software. This particular chunk of code is supposed to interpret a file full of encrypted data and decrypt it, but I keep getting an `IndexError`.

Here's the code:

```
while message_count < message_len:
    if int(ord(message[message_count])-int(key_list[key_count])) >= 0:            
        key_tempvar = str(chr(ord(message_encrypted[message_count])-int(key_list[key_count])))
        message_decrypted = message_decrypted + key_tempvar
    key_count += 1
    if key_count == key_len:
        key_count = 0
    message_count += 1
```

Here's the error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Documents\Code\Python\encryption\ASCII_encrypt.py", line 122, in <module>
    title()
  File "E:\Documents\Code\Python\encryption\ASCII_encrypt.py", line 69, in title
    decrypt(message)
  File "E:\Documents\Code\Python\encryption\ASCII_encrypt.py", line 109, in decrypt
    key_tempvar = str(chr(ord(message_encrypted[message_count])-int(key_list[key_count])))
IndexError: string index out of range
```

`message_count` starts at 0 and `message_len` is equal to the length of the encrypted file. The idea of the code is that each character of `message` goes through the function individually and then gets added to the string `message_decrypted`, then that string gets written to a new file.

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: What `key_list` is?

Comment: @AleksandrSosenko `key_list` is a list of digits that describe the encryption key in ASCII identifiers. It's something like `[112, 156, 78, 90]`, depending on what the encryption key is. It is user input.

Comment: "It is user input." - can you show us the code for `key_list` input and creation?

Comment: What is the difference btw `message` and `message_encrypted`? Can you share more code?

Comment: Insert a `print` after `while` to show the values of `message_count`, `message_len` and `len(message_encrypted)`.

Comment: @AleksandrSosenko Well, you figured it out... lol, `message_encrypted` should've just been `message`. `message_encrypted` was an old variable I deleted and must have forgotten about. Thanks!!